# Cannot convert object to its type

Tags: c#, casting

I have a function that has an input of type object. The value that comes to this function is an array of a class called 'Box' I've made the following tries but not able to convert the `object value` to `Box[]`.

```cs
    internal class BoxConverter : IRunDataConverter
    {
        string IRunDataConverter.Key => "boxes";

        object IRunDataConverter.ConvertToPublishable(object value)
        {
            //return value;

            object[] arr = (object[])value;//value is an array of Box

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(arr[0].GetType());// --> WF.CV.Entity.Box
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(Box));//      --> WF.CV.Entity.Box

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(arr[0].GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);// --> WF.CV.Entity.Box, WF.CV, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(Box).AssemblyQualifiedName);//      --> WF.CV.Entity.Box, WF.CV, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 

            bool sameTypes = typeof(Box) == arr[0].GetType();// FALSE



            Box[] try1 = arr.OfType<Box>().ToArray();// try1 -> array with zero lenght.

            Box[] boxes = new Box[arr.Length];
            for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Box box = (Box)arr[i]; // Error:
                                       // System.InvalidCastException:
                                       // '[A]WF.CV.Entity.Box cannot be cast to
                                       //  [B]WF.CV.Entity.Box. Type A originates from 'WF.CV, Version=1.0.0.0,
                                       //           Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at
                                       //           location 'C:\_koray\korhun\WF\WF.Web\bin\Debug\net5.0\WF.CV.dll'.
                                       //  Type B originates from 'WF.CV, Version=1.0.0.0,
                                       //           Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' in a byte array.'




                dynamic val = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
                val.Name = box.Name;
                val.Confidence = box.Confidence;
                val.Coords = box.Coords;
                boxes[i] = val;
            }
            return boxes;
        }
    }
```

When I type `typeof(Box)` and `arr[0].GetType()` into Immediate Window I get the following result. (Unseen parts in the picture are same.)
[image]

This is the Box class:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OpenCvSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace WF.CV.Entity
{
    [DebuggerDisplay("Name: {Name} Confidence: {Confidence} Location: {Location}")]
    public class Box
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Confidence { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Normalized MinX, MinY, MaxX, MaxY
        /// </summary>
        public float[] Coords { get; set; }
    
        [JsonIgnore]
        public float Left => Coords[0];
        [JsonIgnore]
        public float Right => Coords[2];
        [JsonIgnore]
        public float Top => Coords[1];
        [JsonIgnore]
        public float Bottom => Coords[3];
    
        [JsonIgnore]
        public float Width => Coords[2] - Coords[0];
        [JsonIgnore]
        public float Height => Coords[3] - Coords[1];
    
    
        public Rect GetRect(int width, int height)
        {
            int x = (int)(Coords[0] * width);
            int y = (int)(Coords[1] * height);
            int w = (int)((Coords[2] - Coords[0]) * width);
            int h = (int)((Coords[3] - Coords[1]) * height);
            return new Rect(x, y, w, h);
        }
    
    }
}
```

This happens inside an unsafe dll being used by an Entity Framework and Web API projects, in Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10 environment. All projects' target framework is .NET 5.0.

**Update** - What happens before:

IRunDataConverter is being called with this manager class. It's in a non-unsafe dll:

```cs
public class RunDataConverterManager : IRunDataConverterManager
{
    private readonly ILogger<IRunDataConverter> logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

    public RunDataConverterManager(ILogger<IRunDataConverter> logger, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.provider = provider;
        initialize();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, IRunDataConverter> converters;
    private void initialize()
    {
        this.converters = new Dictionary<string, IRunDataConverter>();

        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(dll));

        var type = typeof(IRunDataConverter);
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass);

        HashSet<string> hs = new();
        foreach (Type ty in types)
            if (hs.Add(ty.AssemblyQualifiedName))
            {
                IRunDataConverter converter = null;
                try
                {
                    converter = create(ty);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.logger.LogError($"Cannot create IRunDataConverter! assemblyName: {ty.AssemblyQualifiedName} typeName: {ty.Name} exception: {ex.GetLogMessage()}");
                }
                if (converter != null)
                {
                    if (this.converters.ContainsKey(converter.Key))
                        throw new Exception($"Duplicated key for IRunDataConverter! There can be only one converter for a key. Key: {converter.Key}");
                    else
                        this.converters.Add(converter.Key, converter);
                }
            }
    }
    private IRunDataConverter create(Type ty)
    {
        //ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34746583/1266873
        return (IRunDataConverter)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(this.provider, ty);
    }



    IRunDataPublishable[] IRunDataConverterManager.ConvertToPublishable(RunData[] data)
    {
        return this.getData(data).ToArray();
    }
    private IEnumerable<IRunDataPublishable> getData(RunData[] data)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<object>> dic = new();
        if (data != null)
            foreach (RunData item in data)
                if (item != null)
                {
                    //this is where it's called
                    object value = this.converters.ContainsKey(item.Key) ? this.converters[item.Key].ConvertToPublishable(item.Value) : item.Value;
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(item.Key))
                        dic.Add(item.Key, new List<object>() { value });
                    else
                        dic[item.Key].Add(value);
                }
        foreach (string key in dic.Keys)
            yield return new runData()
            {
                Key = key,
                Values = dic[key].ToArray()
            };
    }
    private class runData : IRunDataPublishable
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object[] Values { get; set; }
    }
}


//RunData class is in another non-unsafe dll:
[DebuggerDisplay("Key: {Key} Value: {Value}")]
    public class RunData
    {
        public RunnerNode Node { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public RunDataDictionary Children { get; private set; } = new RunDataDictionary();

        public RunData(RunnerNode node, string key, object value)
        {
            this.Node = node; 
            this.Key = key;
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public RunData Clone()
        {
            return new RunData(this.Node, this.Key, this.Value)
            {
                Children = this.Children.Clone()
            };
        }
    }
```

IRunDataConverterManager is a singleton injected item (Startup/ConfigureServices/
`services.AddSingleton<IRunDataConverterManager, RunDataConverterManager>();`)

RunData items, the values are not serialized-deserialized in any way, until the issue I'm facing in the `BoxConverter.ConvertToPublishable` method.

Comment: You mention about unsafe dll and the debugging shows the type originating from a byte array -- has the type been marshalled before this point e.g. from a BinaryReader?

And are you able to cast value directly to a (qualified) WF.CV.Entity.Box[]?

Comment: @Slate directly casting did not work.  I've looked call stack: there is no conversion or any other thing done for on the Box[]. However there is an [External Code] line, where this interface is being called. This instance of interface IRunDataConverter is created by ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(provider, type), but it has nothing to do with the Box class type..

Comment: @Koray The problem is not with types themselves. Your code reduced works fine. What happens with `Box box = arr[i] as Box;` ? Is it null or do you get the relevant ref?

Comment: @Koray Your code reduced works as expected  on my VS2017 .NET Framework Win10-x64 local console: `var array = new Box[1]; array[0] = new Box(); object value = array; object[] arr = (object[])value; Box box = (Box)arr[0];`. Can you add more details about for example `IRunDataConverter` and things you use like JSON, serialization, client-server and/or web tech...

Comment: @Olivier Rogier error on direct casting to array, null when used 'as' and false if we use 'is' I'll update the question and try to show what is happening before this interface being called.

Comment: I actually resolved my issue by deleting the BoxConverter class and simplified the box objects by another approach (by using json serialize ingnore attribute.) However the situation in the question is really interesting to me. I couldn't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the code below.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(dll)) -> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(Assembly.LoadFrom(dll).GetName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Good to see you resolved the issue.

Regarding your update with the extra code -- I'd be really cautious about using the Assembly GetTypes() and the Activator for it. It's always better to create instances of types you have static access to rather than going through reflection or breaking interface rules. I believe GetTypes() returns new type instances, and since Type .Equals/== only checks reference of the underlying system type, then a new instance will not be equal.

I wonder if your problem is the two Box types look the same but the instances are different, then the runtime is not able to convert the two.

Comment: I've changed the GetTypes to a static array of types that is filled only once. GetTypes had been used 2 times so this was a good thing to do; thank you. However, the same issue occured.